# Хром размывает контент при использовании transorm: translate;

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

Помогите есть скриншоты в разных браузерах
`Google Chrome`

[image: chrome]

`Opera`
[image: opera]

Вот код:

```css
  #search {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;

   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,50%);
  }
  #search input {
   padding: 10px 30px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Искать</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="action.php" id="search">
  <input type="text" name="srch" id="srch" placeholder="Искать в интернете.">
  <input type="submit" value="Искать" class="search">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос, почему в хроме все искажено и размыто, а в опере все четко? мне нужно исправить отображение в хроме. translateZ Не использую.

Comment: покажите ваш код.

Comment: вы используете `translateZ()` неявно, потому что используете `translate3d()`, который содержит в себе информацию о сдвиге по всем осям.